# Why is this diff function treating empty cells as different?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, diff

```
def find_diffs(dataframe1, dataframe2):  # Finds diff cells and stores to list
x_ofs = dataframe1.columns.nlevels + 1
y_ofs = dataframe1.index.nlevels + 1
return([column_letter(x + x_ofs) + str(y + y_ofs) for
        y, x in zip(*np.where(dataframe1 != dataframe2))])
```

I'm making a Python script to diff 2 Excel files and highlight the cells that are different.  I'm using a Pandas dataframe.  The problem with this function is that it highlights empty cells as if they're different.  I've tried a few things like:

```
 (dataframe1 != dataframe2) and dataframe2 != ''
 (dataframe1 != dataframe2) and dataframe2 != 'nan'
 (dataframe1 != dataframe2) & dataframe2 != nan
```

I've tried more things but these are just a few examples.  I also tried to make a similar function to detect empty cells and then remove them from the list of cells it considers different, but I can't get that to work.

Side question:  Is there a way to make it ignore case sensitivity?  It also highlights cells when the case of the letters differ

More of the code:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(mxln, header=None)  # Loads master xlsx for comparison
df2 = pd.read_excel(sfcn, header=None)  # Loads student xlsx for comparison
df3 = df2.to_excel('TEACHER COPY ' '[' + sname + '].xlsx')
# difference = df2[df2 != df1]  # Scans for differences
# print(difference)

def find_diffs(dataframe1, dataframe2):  # Finds diff cells and stores to list
    x_ofs = dataframe1.columns.nlevels + 1
    y_ofs = dataframe1.index.nlevels + 1
    return([column_letter(x + x_ofs) + str(y + y_ofs) for
            y, x in zip(*np.where(dataframe1 != dataframe2) & (dataframe2.notnull()))])



# print(find_diffs(df1, df2))

# find_diffs(df1, df2)
# print(find_diffs(df1, df2))

test0 = 'TEACHER COPY ' '[' + sname + '].xlsx'
test = load_workbook(test0)
test1 = test.active
test2 = test.save(test0)
test3 = test1
# test4 = test.active

def color_red():
    redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFEE1111', end_color='FFEE1111', fill_type='solid')
    for cell in find_diffs(df1, df2):  # find_diffs(df1, df2)
        # print(cell)
        test3[cell].fill = redFill
        test.save(test0)
        #return(color_red)  # Leave commented otherwise only colors 1st cell in list

color_red()

def count_red():
    errors = str(len(find_diffs(df1, df2)))
    # print(errors)
    return(errors)

def write_errors():
    wb = load_workbook(filename=test0)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    ws['A27'] = 'Errors:  ' + count_red()
    wb.save(test0)

write_errors()
```

Comment: you are treating pandas df as a numpy array. Try to convert them into np array.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:**

`numpy.nan` doesn't compare equal, as a rule

```
a = np.nan
a == a
Out[61]: False
```

For when this doesn't work out well, there are the methods `isnull` and `notnull`.

Taking this into account, your last attempt was very close:

```
np.where((dataframe1 != dataframe2) & (dataframe2.notnull()))
```

Should do what you're looking for.

**Q2:**
String methods like `.upper` and `.lower` can be accessed from `pd.Series` objects (not `pd.DataFrame` objects though) with the `.str` accessor. E.g. `df[df.columns[0]].str.upper()` would return a series of the values in the first column of `df`, but all uppercase.

Comment: I'm getting an error:  'ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 18: given 2'

Comment: @stackoa Can you post a dataframe and code that reproduces your issue?